# Elliptic Integrals Identity? $kK(k) = K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$

Tags: elliptic-integrals

In the wikipedia page on [Elliptic Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), under the section Complete Elliptic Integrals of the 1st Kind, sub-section "Differential Equation", is the following:-

---

===*Differential equation*===

*The differential equation for the elliptic integral of the first kind is*
$$\frac{d}{dk}\left(k\left(1-k^2\right)\frac{dK(k)}{dk}\right)=k K(k)$$

*A second solution to this equation is $$K\left(\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)$$. This solution satisfies the relation*
$$\frac{d}{dk}K(k)=\frac{E(k)}{k\left(1-k^2\right)}-\frac{K(k)}{k}$$.

---

I interpreted " *a second solution to this equation is*" to imply (by association of the form  S1:$A=B$,  S2:$A=C$ => S3:$A=C$) that:-

$$kK(k) = K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$$

However if I ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+x*EllipticK%5Bx%5D+-+EllipticK%5Bsqrt(1-x%5E2)%5D) to solve:-

$$kK(k) - K(\sqrt{1-k^2}) = ?$$

it gives an answer which is not zero.

(I get a similar problem when looking at the differential of the Complete Elliptic Integral of the 2nd kind, but I will put that aside for now).

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that it means
$$\frac{d}{dk}\left(k\left(1-k^2\right)\frac{dK(\sqrt{1-k^2})}{dk}\right)=k\, K\left(\sqrt{1-k^2}\right).$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. I wonder if I am alone in finding that extremely confusing given that they did not previously declare an unknown quantity. Is it a fairly normal use of language in math?